# Installing pin tool on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded pin Tool from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-binary-instrumentation-tool-downloads). I want help to install it on Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Answer (score 5):

I checked the website. This program does not actually need any installation procedure. To use the package, simply do:

```
cd (your downloaded package's destination)
tar zxf pin-3.2-81205-gcc-linux.tar.gz
cd pin-3.2-81205-gcc-linux
```

and then follow the instructions in the README to use the package's functions. (i.e. `./pin SOMECOMMAND`. )

Comment: I Do that.but cannot know how to Utilize that.i compiled C file from that and it makes .out file so how to open it using that tool